# Faster to run two loops or one loop

Tags: r, for-loop

In general, if the number of iterations of two for loops are the same, is it faster to run two for loops or to combine the two for loops into one for loop?

I would have imagined that running one for loop should be faster, but when I wrote some test code, this was not the case.  Can anyone explain why this is?

Here is some code example in `R`

```
tic <- function(gcFirst = TRUE, type=c("elapsed", "user.self", "sys.self"))
{
   type <- match.arg(type)
   assign(".type", type, envir=baseenv())
   if(gcFirst) gc(FALSE)
   tic <- proc.time()[type]         
   assign(".tic", tic, envir=baseenv())
   invisible(tic)
}

toc <- function()
{
   type <- get(".type", envir=baseenv())
   toc <- proc.time()[type]
   tic <- get(".tic", envir=baseenv())
   print(toc - tic)
   invisible(toc)
}

> tic() 
> for(i in 1:10000){
+ x = rnorm(1000)
+ y = rnorm(1000)
+ }
> toc()
elapsed 
   1.78 
> 
> 
> tic() 
> for(i in 1:10000){
+ x = rnorm(1000)
+ }
> for(i in 1:10000){
+ y = rnorm(1000)
+ }
> toc()
elapsed 
   1.78
```

So as you see, it took one for loop 1.78 seconds and it took the 2 for loops 1.78 seconds as well.

Comment: So, now that they're equal. All better :)

Comment: @Badger But should they be the same? I would have still imagined that one for loop would be faster than running two for loops.

Comment: It' still doing the same number of operations. The counting part is negligible. So I think yes, they should be the same in this case. In the event that you are doing work that would be better done through `aggregate` or something to that effect, you would see superior times.

Answer (score 1):

In two loop example, the second loop only runs to 1000. That probably accounts for the difference. In the general case, it's complicated to answer because it depends on locality, cache size, and what operations you are doing that can be pipelined. The difference is usually negligible and only relevant in performance critical applications. You should probably prioritize clarity of code.

Answer (score 0):

As @adeebm said, this depends a lot on the scenario. Typical one might be iterating over 2D coordinates where both X and Y values are necessary and also the linear ID. The calculation of the linear ID from X and Y involves modulo and division while calculation of X and Y from linear ID involves multiplication and addition which is faster. [Here is an example and test.](https://github.com/ichlubna/codeTestSnippets/blob/main/loops.cpp)